# Condition checking gives wrong answer

Tags: c, bit-shift, operator-precedence, bitwise-and, relational-operators

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("%d,%d\n", 2 & (1<<1) , 2 & (1<<1)>0 );
  return 0;
}
```

the output of this program is `2,0`.

`2 & (1<<1)` is equal to 2 which is more than 0.
so why does `2 & (1<<1) > 0` evaluate to zero??

Comment: 2 & (1<<1) > 0 == 2 & ((1<<1) > 0) == 2 & 1 == 0

Comment: Turn up your warning levels and pay attention to them. They can often give you a pretty good idea of what is really going on. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/o9KWj5K7W). Then, review the language [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) table to understand what is really happening, specifically the precedence differential of `&` vs `>`.

Answer (score 5):

This expression

```
2 & (1<<1)>0
```

is equivalent to

```
2 & ( (1<<1)>0 )
```

due to the precedence of the operators. That is the relational operator > has a higher precedence than the bitwise AND operator.  As `1 << 1` is greater than `0` then the sub-expression `( ( 1 << 1 ) > 0 )` yields the value `1`.

So `2 & 1` yields `0` because in binary `1` can be represented (for simplicity) like `01` and `2` - like `10` and

```
 01
&
 10
---
 00
```

It seems what you mean is the following expression

```
( 2 & ( 1 << 1 ) ) > 0
```